# Can I have a Ubuntu 12.04 live usb work with both the -persistance and -toram additional boot options?

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, live-cd, ram, persistence

I really like using the Ubuntu 12.04 live CD/USB's "-toram" additional boot option for my laptop because "-toram" adds a few extra hours to the battery and makes things a little faster. I add the additional boot options by pressing "F6" as the live CD begins to start. The only problem with the copy live cd to RAM option is that when I have to turn off my computer, I lose the programs I downloaded while in RAM only mode. To solve that problem, can I effectively add "-persistance" (persistent live usb storage) to "-toram"?

I want Ubuntu 12.04 to copy the files saved to RAM into the usb for persistent storage when I click "Shut Down". Then when I boot from usb, I want it to copy all the files (including those saved from the last session) back into RAM.